# Github showing index.html not found

Tags: github

I already uploaded index.html on my Github repo but when I load the site they showed ***For root URLs you must provide an index.html file.***
Repolink:https://github.com/developerHet/simon-game
Site: https://developerhet.github.io/simon-game

Comment: Have you enabled GitHub pages for that repo?

Comment: No. but after enabling, Github pages my query was solved thankyou for your help.

Comment: We prefer you to copy and paste code here instead of sharing links since that can change over time and it wont help futer visiters.